# Actionscript 3 RegExp quantifiers do not seem to work properly?

Tags: regex, actionscript, regex-greedy

In Actionscript 3, I am trying to use regex to test user input. The following code tests a string:

```
private function ValidateModifier(tst:String):Boolean
{
    var validDieRoll:RegExp = /([+-]?)([0-9]+)d([0-9]+)/;
    return ( validDieRoll.test( tst ) );
}
```

It is supposed to allow a + or - sign in the beginning of the string sequence, but ONLY one. However, it seems to be ignoring the ? quantifier to accept any number of + or - signs.

I'm testing with this array of values:

```
tmpArray.push("3d6");
tmpArray.push("d36");
tmpArray.push("-3d6");
tmpArray.push("+d3");
tmpArray.push("++--+3d6");
tmpArray.push("d3");
tmpArray.push("3d");
```

In the following results, the fifth item should have turned up false. What am I missing here?

```
3d6 = true
d36 = false
-3d6 = true
+d3 = false
++--+3d6 = true
d3 = false
3d = false
```

I have tried these permutations of the regex with exactly the same results:

```
var validDieRoll:RegExp = /([+-]{0,1})([0-9]+)d([0-9]+)/;
var validDieRoll:RegExp = /([+-]{0,1}?)([0-9]+)d([0-9]+)/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say a thing about +/- being **in the beginning** of the string sequence. So, your original pattern gives you a match for "++--+3d6", because it does contain what you specified.

Add `^` in the beginning of your pattern, and `$` in the end.

```
var validDieRoll:RegExp = /^([+-]?)(\d+)d(\d+)$/;
```

Comment: Voila! Problem solved. Strangely enough, the original version worked perfectly well in a PHP script.

Comment: It shouldn't have given you the correct results. But that's PHP, I guess they have a global function for that. ))